I have some problem with jmeter json extractor
I use the JSON Extractor to extract the access token for use in the next Thread Group
But the second Thread Group gets a value that doesn't match the value extracted by the JSON Extractor
How can I ensure that the value extracted from the JSON Extractor is correct?

You have at least 10 errors as it evidenced by red 10 next to yellow exclamation mark

So check jmeter.log file and see what exactly failed, once you fix it maybe the value will start "matching"
I also see several Beanshell test elements in your script, it's some form of a performance anti-pattern, since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting.
Groovy has built-in JSON support and in general more fast and powerful than Beanshell, see Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For? article for more details.
